# ASP.NET MVC Custom Initializer only create/update certain tables not whole database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to use MVC EF6 to build my application, but I'm sharing a database with tables from a different application. Because of this, I cannot just drop/create the database if my model changes. How do I redefine my "database" beyond the connection string, to only consist of a couple of tables? I need help because this is eliminating EF6 as a possibility and I feel I could learn something from this. I could theoretically setup yet another database, and make my seed methods query from it, but that would require I describe all tables in EF6 and I really don't want to do that. Any help would be much appreciated! How do I redefine my "database" beyond the connection string, to only consist of a couple of tables, so I can take advantage of Entity Framework in my portion of the database?

Comment: How are you defining the `DbContext`?  Is sounds from your post that you have a `DbContext` in this project, which is independent of the "other application" `DbContext`, with only a subset of tables defined.  If this is the case, I would look at moving the `DbContext` into a shared library that both applications reference.  This would allow you to centralise the migrations, and reliably share the data access.

Comment: Hi Brendan, unfortunately I don't have any control over the other app at all. I thought about using a custom initializer and never calling create/delete for any reason, instead just truncate and fill.. but I'm not sure how the models will react to that?

Comment: if you want to do the migration manually, than it will be an easy job but you have to take care about the generting for the migration script. if you engage EF in your migration story this will be a long story. so tell me what you want and I can help u

Comment: It sounds like EF would best have full control of the whole database. The core of my question comes down to, can I easily define my "database" as table1 and table2 only, or do I just need to put it into its own storage database and be done? The first time I noticed this is when it tried to drop the database, I was glad I didn't have read/write to the whole database.